# VirtualBox Not Starting after Successful Docker Installation

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

Before starting to learn docker, I have been able to open oracle virtual machine. But after following steps on how to install docker on windows, then switching on hyper-v, docker started working but this has made the virtual machine to stop working so I decided to uninstall docker and switch off hyper-v then restart the system, surprisingly, the VirtualBox is still showing similar error like so:

```
Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87 (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Please how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features**, Click on the "**Turn Windows features on or off**", and in the pop-up which appears, do the following

```
 1. turn off Hyper-V by unchecking the Checkbox
 2. turn off Windows Hypervisor Platform unchecking the Checkbox
 3. turn off Windows Sandbox
 4. turn off Containers
```

Reboot when prompted. Then try Virtual Box again, it should work.
Alternatively you can uninstall and reinstall Virtual box. It might work too.

Comment: Following all your steps, I still have the error then I followed your last advice(uninstall then re-install VirtualBox) the error was gone but the virtual OS has been blank since and it doesn't show any error message.Please I seriously need help as my project is inside the virtual OS

Comment: Can you please elaborate what did you mean by virtual OS is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem installing WSL, I just updated virtual box to latest (in my case was) 7.0.10 r158379 (Qt5.15.2) and it worked.

You will not need to disable anything in "optionalfeatures" panel.

I had still version virtualbox 6.

Comment: As the question is old, you might want to give specific details like your version before and after updating, or relevant parameters.